# Javascript - Highlight a column name when clicking on it only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html table (with column names: T1, T2, T3). I want to highlight a column name (T1) ONLY when it is clicked on by the user, the rest of the column names don’t have a highlight (T2, T3). Then when the user clicks on another column name (T2), it is highlighted, but I want all the other column names to be reset with no highlight (T1, T3).

How can I do it using only javascript, css, and/or html? Please dont include JQuery, I cannot use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the code you have tried so far. That way, peers can work on top of it rather than build the whole thing on their own.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('td');

var fnClick = function(){
 var ie = document.querySelectorAll('td');
  for(var x = 0; x < ie.length; x++){
    elems[x].classList.remove("red");
  }
  this.classList.add("red");
}

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
     elems[i].addEventListener("click", fnClick);
}
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking, iterate through all column names and remove the class, lets say, "highlight".

After that add the class "highlight" to the column name clicked.

Or, look for elements by class name "highlight", and remove the class from all of them, then proceed to add the class to the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add an unique class to all the column elements for example- T1 for T1, T2 for T2, etc.

Then create a css class "highlight" with appropriate background color to create the highlight effect.

Then within the tags write an onclick function call like `<td class="T1" onclick="addHighlight(T1)">...</td>`

After that you can use JavaScript to create a function 'addHighlight' which is triggered when the user clicks on a column element. Within that function you can use `getElemenstbyClassname` to access the elements with class name of the column that was clicked(you passed in the class name use it as a parameter) and `addClass` method to add the class highlight.

To remove the highlight effect once another column is clicked just search for elements with the class "highlights" and use `removeClass` to remove that class and thus the highlight effect.

Refer to w3schools.com for further guidance. All is clearly explained there :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by styling the [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo class for your td elements. In order to make your td element focus-able you would have  to  set the [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute to your td elements as well.

#### Index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Table Highlight
    </title>
    <style>
      table {
        border: solid;
      }
      td {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: dotted 1px;
      }

      td:focus {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td tabindex="1">T1</td>
        <td tabindex="1">T2</td>
        <td tabindex="1">T2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>22</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a codepen as POC:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKMgvJ

If you want to highlight the corresponding column name (table head element) of the clicked table cell, then you would need to add a click handler on your table.